# How are draws without replacement formalized?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Suppose I have some i.i.d. random variables $X_1,\dots,X_{n}$ which represent the $nth$  balls drawn uniformly from a bin without replacement. Is sampling without replacement a condition that is put on the set I define my probability measure on? In that all elements $w\in \Omega$ are such that they do not have repeated draws? Or is it a property of the random variable with which I use to sample?

Answer (score 0):

It will be defined by the sample space, since you are only allowing outcomes that have no repeating elements.

So your sample space consists of $K \choose n$ unique selections of balls times $n!$ ways of arranging them or a total size of ${K \choose n}n! $